# gamepad of old tv console conversion to play in pc

Tags: gaming

I have an old gamepad it has a female db9 end it has 5 wires in total i saw when I opened it   i just want to convert it to usb and play using my pc as it was earlier for the tv console.What should be the wiring to convert it.

Comment: Can you please reformat your question? It is really hard to read

Comment: I think this is a question for the electronics section of stackexchange.
Just as a heads up though, there are generic db9 to usb converters availible. I'd suggest trying that before modifying and possibly breaking the controller itself.